# Is CSS3 part of HTML5?

Tags: html, css

Is CSS3 part of HTML5? 

It means if a browser supports CSS3, will  it support HTML5 elements too?

I had tried HTML5 elements in IE9, They didnt work. 

But CSS3 properties( like `box-shadow`, `border-radius`) do work in IE9 fine by doing little changes in html file (By putting this tag `<!DOCUMENT HTML>`).

So what do we have to say now?

Does IE9 supports HTML5 or It supports only CSS3 but not HTML5?

Comment: You would find that box-shadow and border-radius would still work without the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: You do not have to say thanks to every single answer to your question as it is considered noise. Just click the upvote arrow.

Comment: @Joshnh Is it? But it is working in IE9 if I put document tag <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">. But it works in other browsers...

Comment: @BoltClock I disagree. I found it to be a nice, personal touch, and I am disappointed to see that you have removed it. Helping people is very personable, and is not something that should be hidden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML5 and CSS3 are completely separate things, so browser support for one does not always mean the other, especially considering that HTML5 is still a working draft (CSS3 is currently a recommendation).

That being said, with todays modern browsers, most will support the common HTML5 and CSS3 features. Internet Explorer 9 still requires a little help in regards to HTML5, you can use what is known as a HTML Shiv (or shim) to 'polyfill' support. Here is a guide to what IE9 supports: http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-support-ie9/

Comment: CSS3 is mostly in draft, but not quite as a single whole specification; some modules have already graduated as standards. Most other modules still are in draft, though.

Comment: No, I meant I'm not sure why you wrote that, I agree with you 100%.

Comment: Yep, HTML5 is only informally used to refer to "the latest web technologies" comprising of HTML5, CSS3 and the latest additions to JavaScript. It is only part of these new technologies but sometimes labelled this way because HTML is the fundamental language for creating webpages.

Comment: @BoltClock, yes, your comment if off, please re-read the answer carefully, esp. where it say what draft is for.

Comment: Obviously I shouldn't be nitpicking on this stuff as it just leads to even more confusion. Never mind.

Answer (score 2):

[Internet Explorer 9 Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410106#_HTML5)

> Internet Explorer 9 builds on the work done on HTML5 compliance in Internet Explorer 8, and implements the following new features:
>
> - HTML5 Geolocation APIs
> - The new video and audio HTML elements
> - The new canvas HTML element
> - The Selection interface
> - More interoperable HTML parsing
> - Several new DOM APIs, as discussed in the DOM L2 HTML section of this document
> - Scaling Vector Graphics (SVG)

Sources other than Microsoft

[Is IE9 a modern browser?](http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/ie9/)

[HTML5 Support in Internet Explorer 9](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-support-ie9/)

Answer (score 1):

HTML5, EcmaScript 5/6, CSS3 are all the newest versions of the languages. As such, they are being implemented roughly at the same time. However, other than that, they are unrelated. Supporting multiple file upload doesn't imply you support border-radius.

It's a bit like saying are ipod docks part of electric cars - they are both new, and there is a correlation between cars with the docks, and electric cars, but that's just because they are both new. (PS, I know nothing about cars, and don't even own one!)

Comment: +I always enjoy comparison like this :)